# How to user LINQ to convert list to dictionary?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

This is my first question in here ever.

I want to store the Meters in a Dictionary where MeterUID is the Key and Meter is the value.
This is the code i have:

```
public static List<Meter> LoadMeterListFromFile()
{
    var meters = new List<Meter>();

    foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\MyLog.Log"))
    {
        var columns = line.Split(';');
        meters.Add(new Meter
         {
             TimeStamp = columns[0],
             MeterUID = columns[1],
             Something1 = Convert.ToInt32(columns[2].Replace("Something1=", "")),
             Something2 = Convert.ToInt32(columns[3].Replace("Something2=", "")),
             Something3 = Convert.ToInt32(columns[4].Replace("Something3=", "")),
             Something4 = Convert.ToInt32(columns[5].Replace("Something4=", "")),
             Something5 = Convert.ToInt32(columns[6].Replace("Something5=", ""))
        });
    }

    return meters;
}
```

But im not sure how to do this, so i hope you guys can help.

Comment: So you want to keep the object as value and `object.MeterUID` as key ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var dict = meters.ToDictionary(m => m.MeterUID, m => m);
```

Comment: Apparently, we think alike :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply try this:

```
var metersDict= meters
               .ToDictionary(e => e.MeterUID , StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the method signature to `IDictionary<string, Meter>` and then call `ToDictionary` before returning the list,

```
public static IDictionary<string, Meter> LoadMeterListFromFile()
{
    var meters = new List<Meter>();

    // ...
    // current implementation

    return meters.ToDictionary(meter => meter.MeterUID);
}
```

Your method however, can be improved by returning an `IEnumerable<Meter>` and using the `yield` to return one element at a time,

```
public static IEnumerable<Meter> LoadMeterListFromFile()
{
    foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\MyLog.Log"))
    {
        var columns = line.Split(';');
        yield return new Meter
            {
                TimeStamp = columns[0],
                MeterUID = columns[1],
                Something1 = Convert.ToInt32(columns[2].Replace("Something1=", "")),
                Something2 = Convert.ToInt32(columns[3].Replace("Something2=", "")),
                Something3 = Convert.ToInt32(columns[4].Replace("Something3=", "")),
                Something4 = Convert.ToInt32(columns[5].Replace("Something4=", "")),
                Something5 = Convert.ToInt32(columns[6].Replace("Something5=", ""))
            };
    }
}
```

And then converting the result to a dictionary,

```
var meters = LoadMeterListFromFile().ToDictionary(meter => meter.MeterUID);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple:

```
var dict = meters.ToDictionary( m => m.MeterUID, m => m);
```